# Accelerometer switch to trigger LED fade

Tags: capacitor, switches, accelerometer

I'm planning out a very simple circuit using an LED, capacitor, switch and a battery.

The Idea is that the LED is off until something "bumps into" the circuit. At this point it should light up and slowly dim out.

I could use a microcontroller, but it would be nicer to be able to solve it with just a large capacitor and something that can trigger it.

Is there such a thing as a switch that triggers (like a reed?) on impact?

I'm grateful for any other ideas or pointers on the circuit!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a form of accelerometer that is commonly seen on kids toys, is super cheap, and works reasonably well when calibration isn't critical.  It's made from a spring and a metal post...

Imagine this:  start with a simple spring like what you'd find in a ball-point pen.  Inside the spring is a simple metal post (or a piece of solid-core wire without insulation).  The post and spring are mounted together on one end and the other end flops in the breeze.  Normally, the spring and post do not make electrical contact.

When this is struck (or, what it's mounted to is struck) the spring with deflect and contact the post, thus making electrical contact.  It only responds to force perpendicular to the post, so you might need a second one to get "3d response".  Vary the spring and post to change the sensitivity.

Here's a photo of one I just whipped up in the lab:  [image: Simple accelerometer]

Ignore the other stuff on the PCB.  I took a stiff piece of wire (not stiff enough, IMHO) and soldered it down.  Then I took a spring from a pen, unwound a little bit of it and soldered it down.  Then bend whatever you need to in order to get the wire centered on the spring.

Comment: That's a great idea. Besides building one from scratch, it would be great to find someone selling these..

Comment: you broad knowledge scope and ability to explain well is much appreciated. Keep it up!

Comment: @Mattias  I doubt that you'll find anyone selling these things pre-made.  But they are super easy to make, so...   @Kellenjb  Thanks!   @All  I added a picture!

Comment: super cool implementation!

Comment: Nice. I created something similar awhile back. Only did the opposite and put the spring inside a metal tube. This way it could be sealed up and handled more agressively.

Comment: this is genius :)

Comment: This is neat. The circuit needs a latching mechanism, too. Here's one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30921/2118

Comment: Late to the party, but these *are* available [pre-made](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1767).

Answer (score 1):

*David Kessner*'s [simple mechanical suggestion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/13073/2118) is great! It needs a latching mechanism to properly trigger an analog circuit, turning on at the slightest spike and holding that state for a little while (as the LED fades).

I'm not sure if this'll work, but I gave it a shot:

[image: 'Fast-On', 'Slow-Off' Latching Momentary Switch]

Comment: mistake: Q3 gate needs a pullup, but RQ1E is small, so an another NPN is needed to drive Q3.

Comment: This is why you should draw circuit answers in [Circuit Lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) - You can edit the linked posts without redrawing completely or resorting to gimp/photoshop!