# Motion sensing LED "Quantum Bits"

Tags: led

I would like to DIY [Quantum Bits](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/f25e/?pfm=Search&t=quantum%20bits).

What could I use that would sense the vibrations/motion?

I'd basically need that, a small battery, some leds, and... what else?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell from the video on the link.  But based on the price, I doubt that they are using a real accelerometer sensor chip.

More likely, they are using a simple spring type sensor like what [I show in this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13071/accelerometer-switch-to-trigger-led-fade/13073#13073).

If I had to guess at a circuit, this is what my guess would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLYxZM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note:  I completely guessed on the value for the caps and resistors.

The circuit works like this:  Normally the LED is powered dimly through R1 and R3.  SW1 is the spring and wire based accelerometer I mentioned earlier.  When SW1 is closed, C2 quickly charges up (at a rate defined by R2) and is discharged through R3 and the LED.  The battery normally has a high internal resistance, and C1 is used to counteract that when SW1 is closed.

Change R3 to set the max current through the LED.  Change R1 to set the normal "steady" brightness of the LED.  Change C2 and R2 to vary the length of time the LED is bright.  And make C1 large enough that it's voltage doesn't change too much when SW1 is closed briefly.

It is possible that R2 is not needed.  It is less likely, but still possible, that C1 is also not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't actually need batteries for making something like that, nor an accelerometer or other sensor:

A piezoelectric cell, such as a tiny piezoelectric speaker, can be used as a vibration energy gathering source.

An energy harvesting IC such as the [Linear Technology LTC3588-1](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/35881fa.pdf) will be able to harvest this energy, and charge up a capacitor.

[image: Schematic]

A simple hysteresis circuit driven off the V<sub>out</sub> line can be used to flash an LED each time sufficient energy (voltage) builds up on the capacitor.

No batteries, autonomously powered, minimal parts.

As the vibration on the device increases, charge will build up faster on the C<sub>storage</sub> capacitor, hence the LED will flash faster. **No additional sensors required**.